# JQuery add class on select change event

Tags: jquery, select

My select button is defined as follows:

```
<select class="gfield_select" tabindex="0" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"><option value="" selected="selected" class="gf_placeholder">Salutation *</option><option value="Miss">Miss</option><option value="Ms.">Ms.</option><option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option><option value="Mr.">Mr.</option></select>
```

I am looking to add a class 'newclass' to the select button, when the user makes any selection apart from the default option. i.e. when the option with class "gf_placeholder" is not selected.

I suppose I need to work on this event:

```
$('select').change(function(){

})
.change();
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body of your `change` callback function needs one line, using `toggleClass`:

```
$(this).toggleClass("newclass", !!$(this).val());
```

The second argument to that method is a boolean that will be true when the value of the selected option is not empty.

```js
$('select').change(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("newclass", !!$(this).val());
}).change();
```

```css
.newclass { background: #ccf; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<select class="gfield_select" tabindex="0" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="" selected="selected" class="gf_placeholder">Salutation *</option>
    <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
    <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
    <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
    <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
</select>
```